# applying a lambda function on Dataframe giving errors

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe named result :

```
result.head(5)
Out[60]: 
          Product_name                                           metadata  \
0           like minds  {'Title': 'Like Minds', 'Year': '2006', 'Rated...   
1  16 years of alcohol  {'Title': '16 Years of Alcohol', 'Year': '2003...   
2                grimm  {'Title': 'Grimm', 'Year': '2011–2017', 'Rated...   
4               gisaku  {'Title': 'Gisaku', 'Year': '2005', 'Rated': '...   
5         deadly cargo  {'Title': 'Tarantulas: The Deadly Cargo', 'Yea...   

   Year Rated  
0  1900     U  
1  1900     U  
2  1900     U  
4  1900     U  
5  1900     U
```

I'm using a function named extract_info to separate various filed in the metadata column whose each element is a dictionary.

```
def extract_info(info_dict):
    return (info_dict['Year'], info_dict['Rated'])
```

Somehow the Metadata column elements are getting interpreted as a string sequence. Unable to understand why so ?

```
result['Year'], result['Rated'] = result['metadata'].apply(lambda x : extract_info(x))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-70a1390b0278> in <module>
----> 1 result['Year'], result['Rated'] = result['metadata'].apply(lambda x : extract_info(x) )

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3589             else:
   3590                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3591                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3592 
   3593         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-63-70a1390b0278> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 result['Year'], result['Rated'] = result['metadata'].apply(lambda x : extract_info(x) )

<ipython-input-61-95b953ff8485> in extract_info(info_dict)
      1 def extract_info(info_dict):
----> 2     return (info_dict['Year'], info_dict['Rated'])
      3 

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How shall I proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is convert column to `dictionaries` before apply your function, because `string`s:

```
import ast
result['Year'], result['Rated'] = result['metadata'].apply(lambda x : extract_info(ast.literal_eval(x)))
```

Comment: giving me "ValueError: malformed node or string" error.

Comment: @Sarang - if change `ast.literal_eval` to `json.loads` same error?

Comment: @Sarang - Also are values strings? `print (type(result['metadata'].iat[0]))` is string?

Comment: json.loads gives TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Comment: print (type(result['metadata'].iat[0])) : <class 'dict'>

Comment: @Sarang - How working my original first solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59117982/revisions), I think 1?

Comment: returning a series from the function also gives same TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: One idea - is possible change `def extract_info(info_dict):
    return (info_dict['Year'], info_dict['Rated'])` to `def extract_info(info_dict):
    return (info_dict.get('Year'), info_dict.get('Rated'))` ?

Comment: its behaving as a str and gives the error : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @Sarang - are data confudental? If not, is possible create pickle by `result[['metadata']].to_pickle('metadat.pkl')` and send it to my email from my profile?

Comment: @Sarang - Is problem find me email? Please run code inmy profile for email